# how to use the bbclass in yocto-fido

Tags: yocto

How can I use `bbclass` in a recipe. Is there any dependencies to use this `bbclass` or  directly can I use?
e.g

```
inherit autotools
inherit systemd
```

In what situation I need to use the above bbclasses. I've read  the mega-manual but I did not understand anything. Please explain how to use bbclasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inherit classes to bring their functionality to your recipe.
For example, inheriting systemd class gives you ability to set files for installation to your package(s).

```
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "connman.service"
```

Or you can disable auto-start of you services by using

```
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "disable"
```

For every special case of using bbclass you should refer to documentation.
If you need samples of usage, just do a grep on your "meta-*" folders and you will find a lot of recipes with actual usage of class.

```
grep -rI "inherit autotools" ./
```

Comment: Thanks @metamorphling, I'm understanding something about bbclass thanks .

Comment: Is there any documents for this with complete discription with examples, thanks.

Comment: @VadalasettiSivanageswararao I believe you are using 1.8 codenamed "fido", that makes it this link http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/mega-manual/mega-manual.html  Look at "Chapter 26. Classes"